# Getting error server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe. My server keeps changing back to permission 710 automatically

Tags: .htaccess, server, permissions

So I've been using a VPS server from namecheap for the past 2 yrs or so and I use it to host some of my clients websites and dashboards to manage mobile apps. Since yesterday around noon all my websites & dashboards started loading the following error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I contacted my hosting support and they said my home folder for my server was set to permission 710 and using SSH on my WHM dashboard they changed to 711, right after that all my websites, dashboards and even mobile apps came back online and started working, then around 15 minutes later it happened again, I again contacted hosting support and they did the same process and everything came back online, I started to see a pattern here so I asked if they could explain how they changed permissions to 711 on SSH so I can do this myself if needed.

Well its been around 10hrs now and my websites, dashboards & mobile apps keep doing the same thing they go offline and cannot be accessed (For mobile apps they don't load any information) until I access WHM and change my home folder to permission 711.

So I know it has something to do with an htaccess file but have no idea which one or even why its automatically being changed every 15 minutes or so. One of the possibilities mentioned by hosting support was that I may have malware (Wouldn't know how) or one of my scripts uploaded has issues causing my whole server to keep crashing.

I already deleted the 2 scripts uploaded in the last two days but that didn't seem to fix anything, and hosting support takes so long to give me just the most basic answers but most importantly they are just giving me temporary fixes and say they have no idea why this is happening.

I am considering downloading each one of my scripts one by one until im only left with my main site and then start uploading them again one by one to see if I can locate the script causing all of this.

If you have any other ideas on why this could be happening I would really appreciate it if you guys can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. check if there is any cron job running, 2. check your system log file, 3. grep through your scripts for typical functions like file handling and mode changing.

Comment: I did add a cron job about 2 weeks ago for changing the permission to certain folders but that was a while back, could this be affecting my server today?

Comment: Well, how should _we_ answer to that? We don't know your settings for the cronjob, we don't know what the cronjob does, it is _your_ system, _cour_ cronjob. Only _you_ can tell. But certainly a cronjob that changes permissions sounds interesting here, doesn't it?

Comment: Looks like that was the case, a crone job was still active and was changing the home folder permission from 711 to 710. Even though the cron job was setting different permissions to other folders that were deleted. I guess you learn something new everyday. Thanks!